# Blender 2.91 wont recognize nvidia gpu

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

I did a fresh install with Manjaro 20 and just installed blender. I am running a RTX 2060 6gb GPU CUDA nor OPTIX see the gpu. I have the current nvidia 455.45.1 driver installed. Blender 2.91 wont recognize nvidia gpu.

Comment: That should be the right driver for CUDA, but looking at this post, it seems that there are still many compatibility issues that need addressing - https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dropping-all-legacy-and-older-nvidia-drivers/36338

Comment: how did you install blender from official repos? snap? flatpak?